# jquery statement not working in ie9 object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, flexslider

having a nightmare.. my website is working in all my browsers except for well you probably can guess what for ie9.. im using 2 jquery plugins one of them is flexslider..

it says in the console that the 
object doesn't support this property or method flexslider and points the line

1st bug -  `$('.flexslider').flexslider({`

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function() {
           $('.flexslider').flexslider({
               animation: "slide",
                directionNav: false
             }); 
         });
   </script>
```

2nd bug - `$( '#cbp-qtrotator' ).cbpQTRotator();

```
      <script src="js/jquery.cbpQTRotator.js"></script>
        <script>
         $( '#cbp-qtrotator' ).cbpQTRotator();
        </script>
```

anyone know how to fix this to make it work on ie9 would be a real great help.. the site is www.fuss-beauty.com

***UPDATE*********

managed to solve my problem... was uploading two jquery files.. didn't realise foundation came with a js file... so annoying.... so i have now relised.. you can only have one js file running... just let everyone know...

Comment: How are you including the scripts? <script> tags? please include them in your question.

Comment: thanks for the reply yep include the tags ive updated my question include the files aswell in the head of my page!! really confussed why it doesnt work..

Comment: I meant then <script src="flexslider.js"></script> for jquery and the two plugins, there's no reason the two would work in chrome and not IE9 unless the plugins themselves use console.log(), or teh way the scripts are beign included IE9 is ignoring them.

Comment: yep include them both and use jquery 2.0... not sure why either having a real problem with it.. know its a pain but do you have ie9 and check my site... just to see if its not just my computer.. its www.fuss-beauty.com been reading aload of stuff and still cant get to the bottom of it.. thanks

Answer (score -2):

I managed to solve my problem: I was uploading two jquery files, didn't realise foundation came with one. So annoying, I now have realized you can only have one js file runningat the same time.